# How to perform a calculation inside a list with an arithmetic operator inside the list in Python?

Tags: python, list, function, for-loop

I'm trying to get create a program, which does basic arithmetic operations addition,
subtraction, multiplication and division on a string expression, such as:

```
"12 + 24"
"23 - 21"
"12 // 12"
"12 * 21"
```

For instance, if we have the string expression: "1 + 2", we have:

```
1 followed by a space
...then followed by an operator
...then followed by another space
...then followed by a 2
```

The challenge of this exercise is to extract the values and the operator from the string expression!

I am stuck on how to extract the operator from the list and use it to perform the operation.

My code is:

```
number = input("Enter: ")
myList = list(number)

print(myList)

for eachValue in myList:

       value = eachValue 

print(value)
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Try this `eval("12 + 24)"?

Comment: You don't want `list(number)`.  That produces a list where every element is one character.  What you want is `myList = number.split()`.  That divides the string into words.

Comment: Could you [edit] your post to concretely describe your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to handle such expressions:

```py
import re
from operator import add, sub, floordiv, mul
operators = {"+":add, "-":sub, "//":floordiv, "*":mul}
expr = input("Enter arithmetic expression: ")
m = re.search(r'^\s*(\d+)\s*(\+|-|//|\*)\s*(\d+)\s*$', expr)
valid = False
if m:
    elements = m.groups()
    if len(elements) == 3 and elements[0].isdigit() and elements[1] in operators and elements[2].isdigit():
        valid = True
if not valid:
    print('not a valid expression')
else:
    result = operators[elements[1]](int(elements[0]), int(elements[2]))
    print(result)
```

Explanation:

- Create a dictionary to map from string versions of the integer operators `+, -, //, *` to [function equivalents of these operators](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html)
- Use the [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) function [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to parse the input expression string capturing `operand`, `operator`, `operand` as `re` groups; the sample code above accepts formatting like "1+1", "1 + 1", "  1 + 1  ", among others
- Validate the input expression: operands must look like integers (checked using [`str.isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit))and the operator string must be in our dictionary
- Evaluate the expression by looking up the appropriate operator in our dictionary and calling it with the two operands (converted to integers) as arguments.

Examples:

```
Enter arithmetic expression: 6 // 2
3

Enter arithmetic expression: 1 + 1
2

Enter arithmetic expression: 5 * 3
15

Enter arithmetic expression:      1 - 99
-98

Enter arithmetic expression: 17/3
not a valid expression
```

NOTE: An alternative, as indicated in the comments to your question, is to use [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) on the input expression, but I have assumed above that you are trying to understand how to code a subset of the logic within `eval()` for basic arithmetic operations.

Comment: @Alex Do you need additional help with your question?